# UNIX SIGNAL TO AUTOSYS

Tags: java, unix, autosys

We have a bunch of java process to be run scheduled at various times in AUTOSYS server.
Most of the java processes doesn't have a exit statement and hence we have written few stop jobs as in shell scripts to kill the process that are running at their scheduled stopping time. When we kill these process ,the Autosys job status is set to Terminated and thence we are receiving the alarms unnessarily.

Currently we are using KILL -9 PROCESS_ID command to kill the process which is setting the autosys job to TE.

Is there any UNIX command which can exit the process smoothly so that the AUTOSYS status is changed to SU (success) ? .

Answer (score 2):

The simplest thing to do is wrap the invocation of java within a shell script that reads the termination exit codes and on reading an exit code that represents termination by a signal then exits with a 0 return code.

e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash -p

java dothestuff
rc=$?
if [ $rc -eq 130 ]; then
    echo "Killed by SIGINT"
    exit 0
fi
exit $rc
```

Comment: Thanks for the response , But in my project the java service which is called at java dothestuff ( here the java is a while infinite loop and there is no system.exit in the java files ) ,wouldn't rc variable be empty in this case ?

Comment: The JVM will terminate with a non-zero exit code when it is killed by a signal.